# Cannot bridge point-to-point between autonomous AP and lightweight AP

Tags: cisco, wireless, ieee-802.11, bridge, capwap

I'm doing some tests in a company, and I have some problems.

My mission is to configure an autonomous AP Cisco AIRCAP-2602E, and do a Wi-Fi bridge point-to-point between a Cisco lightweight AP and the autonomous AP (which is the Cisco AIRCAP-2602E).

The lightweight AP is connected to a Cisco Wi-Fi controler and my autonomous AP is alone.

I just want to do a bridge between these two APs to broadcast the network (from the vlan 10), which is broadcast by the lightweight AP on the Gigabit interface of my autonomous AP that will be linked to a computer.

But, I'm searching on the web for a solution. I have tested a lot of things, and nothing works. I cannot bridge between these APs.

I don't have much knowledge about the Wi-Fi with Cisco. I tried a lot of things like set up bridge-group, do universal root bridge, etc., but nothing works.

What is the good mode for the autonomous AP? How do I connect them together?

I'm so lost please help me...

*Sory for my bad english, I've done my best...*
*If you have questions for some precision ask me*

Comment: Instead of a point-to-point link, would you settle for the WAP as a workgroup bridge? It would simply be a client of the LWAP.

Comment: I don't know how to do that with the autonomous Cisco AP, but i can do this yes. I will try that if i can and if I found something... Thanks for your help, I hope i will find something!!! :)

Comment: I will provide an answer if you can do it that way.

Comment: Aha if you do that you will be my god for a long time lol !

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the WAP to be a client of the LWAP. The WAP would act as a wireless bridge. It will not be a point-to-point link, but the WAP will bridge the devices connected to its ethernet interface to the LWAP.

Apparently, you can only configure this for one radio in the WAP. In the radio configuration, use the `station-role workgroup-bridge` command. Cisco provides an example:

```
AP# configure terminal
AP(config)# interface dot11radio 0
AP(config-if)# station-role workgroup-bridge
AP(config-if)# ssid infra
AP(config-ssid)# infrastructure-ssid
AP(config-ssid)# authentication client username wgb1 password cisco123
AP(config-ssid)# exit
AP(config-if)# exit
AP(config)# workgroup-bridge client-vlan 22
AP(config)# end
```

One hitch is that the WAP as a bridge can time out the MAC addresses of the clients it is bridging, if they do not send very often, even if they are receiving. You can increase the timeout for this problem:

```
configure terminal
bridge <bridge-group-number> <aging-time seconds>
exit
end
```

Cisco has the full set of instructions on configuring a workgroup bridge, e.g. [*Cisco IOS Configuration Guide for Autonomous Aironet Access Points Cisco IOS Release 15.3(3)JAB*](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/access_point/15-3-3/configuration/guide/cg15-3-3/cg15-3-3-chap19-wgb-standby.html). In particular, there is a section on configuring a workgroup bridge, and a following section on how to work with a workgroup bridge as a client of an LWAP.

> ## Understanding Workgroup Bridge Mode
>
> You can configure access points as workgroup bridges. In workgroup
>   bridge mode, the unit associates to another access point as a client
>   and provides a network connection for the devices connected to its
>   Ethernet port. For example, if you need to provide wireless
>   connectivity for a group of network printers, you can connect the
>   printers to a hub or to a switch, connect the hub or switch to the
>   access point Ethernet port, and configure the access point as a
>   workgroup bridge. The workgroup bridge associates to an access point
>   on your network.
>
> If your access point has two radios, either the 2.4-GHz radio or the
>   5-GHz radio can function in workgroup bridge mode. When you configure
>   one radio interface as a workgroup bridge, the other radio remains up.
>   However, both radios cannot be configured to operate simultaneously as
>   a workgroup bridge. The other radio can either be disabled (shutdown),
>   or be in root (access point or bridge), scanner, or spectrum mode.

Comment: I try it, I keep you in touch, thanks for tour help!

Comment: Hello guys, i still have problem because the "authentication client username wgb1 password cisco123" is for wep security and not for WPA-PSK.. Please help me :/

Comment: In that document, under the repeater mode, there are instructions for how to configure WPA2 authentication as a client. Just use that instead of what you are trying to use. I'm not sure of what you mean about the VLAN. VLANs are used on ethernet, but they translate to SSIDs for Wi-Fi. Each VLAN should be assigned to a different SSID.